# What is the use of SetEnv in Apache configuration

Tags: linux, apache

I am a complete newb to Apache Servers. So far, I understand that Apache configuration is made in httpd.conf but there is one environment variable called SetEnv that has been bugging me. In one demo code I am looking at, there is

SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

and in another folder, I can see a "development" folder with other php files in it with database configurations. So, I am kind of not very clear as to the use of SetEnv. Does it point to files that will show DB configs?

Answer (score 0):

SetEnv sets an internal environment variable in apache that you can use in apache modules or pass to CGI scripts.

Syntax is :- `SetEnv variable value`

So in `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"` you can use APPLICATION_ENV as a variable and apache will use it's value="development" instead.